# Is there a way to replace Django's smart_str with a Python native solution?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am passing with a code base that is using the `smart_str` method of Django:

```
 for p in pro:
        print smart_str(p["title"])
```

I want to replace it with a native python solution without involving django inside but I am not sure what `smart_str` exactly do:

> `smart_str(s, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict')`
>
> Alias of smart_bytes() on Python 2 and smart_text() on Python 3. This
>   function returns a str or a lazy string.

and

> `smart_bytes(s, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False,errors='strict')`
>
> Returns a bytestring version of s, encoded
>   as specified in encoding.
>
> If strings_only is True, don’t convert (some) non-string-like objects.

Could we replace it simply with `print unicode(u'\xa1').encode("utf-8")`?

Comment: It is *"Python native"*, see [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/92053acbb9160862c3e743a99ed8ccff8d4f8fd6/django/utils/encoding.py). It handles a lot more cases than your suggested alternative does.

Comment: I see, so I just copy the code of `smart_byte` and `force_byte` functions to be independent of django

Comment: Also you'll need to implement (or at least provide a dummy for) `django.utils.functional.Promise` to use them as is.

Comment: It's too dependent to the module `django.utils.six` , I want an independent solution that I can at least save it as one module.

Comment: Then it's up to you to decide how much of the functionality you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replaced it with this dummy function that apply `unicode(x).encode("utf-8")` if the string is unicode, and convert it to `str` if it's a number:

```
def smart_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, unicode):
        return unicode(x).encode("utf-8")
    elif isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float):
        return str(x)
    return x
```